# Rigidbody2D or raycasting?

Tags: unity-game-engine, unity3d-2dtools

I am working on a 2D game that involves many blocks that stack and collide on eachother and the player. I am currently using Rigidbody2D on the blocks for dynamic collisions but I am not a fan of how the dynamic physics include the "bounciness" in the elastic collisions. Also, there is an inherent push-force as well as other unfavorable push physics that are too "realistic".

I am wondering what is the best way to handle my predicament to remove the bounciness and push elements of the rigid bodies. I've tried adjusting the block's masses and bounciness physics but no luck. Is there a way to set them all as kinematic or disable these realistic effects somehow and still have them collide via rigidbodies? (Kinematic would be great if they were able to collide with each other) Or will I have to create some sort of raycast based block physics handling script? Or is there an even better solution to creating this very primitive physics structure that I am not seeing?

Thanks for any and all help!

Comment: You can get okay behaviours out of the stock controllers, but it can get unintuitively tedious; I guess it would depend on the precision you need. Raycast controllers, imo are extremely precise and robust, especially for 2d.

Comment: To be honest i'm kind of new to physics controlling in unity, would you mind posting some examples or stuff to read that'll help me? I'm not sure which stock controllers you are referring too. I thought that raycasting was not very precise but I must not be implementing it properly. Anything helps.

Comment: I was referring to the Rigidbody controller when I was referring to the stock controller; lazy phrasing, sorry.

Raycast controllers, from my experience, have been extremely accurate. [Here's](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OBtaLCmJexk)  a crash course.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only way I could think of solving your problem, such that you have complete intuitive accuracy, is to write your own Rigidbody controller. Of course you can still reuse the Box colliders.

Once you've decided on a collision detection method and manifold generation working (raycasting maybe), [this](https://gamedevelopment.tutsplus.com/tutorials/how-to-create-a-custom-2d-physics-engine-the-basics-and-impulse-resolution--gamedev-6331) link details the impulse resolution you need.